# Oracle 11 g listener wont start

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

A few hours earlier I posted this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183101/cant-connect-my-java-application-to-my-oracle-11g) that I can't connect my java application to Oracle database , no solutiuon so far.

But after some research I found that the listener is not started , I mean it gives me an error when I try to start the listener through LSNCTRL that says :

```
 Message 1070 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNSTNS-125
 60: Message 12560 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNS
 TNS-00530: Message 530 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility
 =TNS
```

And when I try to see the status of the Listener it says :

```
Message 1053 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNSTNS-125
41: Message 12541 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNS
TNS-12560: Message 12560 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facili
ty=TNS
TNS-00511: Message 511 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facilit
y=TNS
 32-bit Windows Error: 61: Unknown error
```

So can someone tell me whats wrong ?

Comment: Looks like your Oracle database is not correctly/completely installed.  Can you re-install it?

Comment: I'd guess that your Oracle Home isn't set properly.  Which O/S are you on?

Comment: when you start the listener there should be also an os error

Comment: there is no os errors , just the errors i am talking about here

Answer (score 3):

Most of these Message not found error due to not setting the ORACLE_HOME properly.
Set the ORACLE_HOME properly and see if you still getting this error.

Comment: Could you explain *how* one might set it properly, and how to tell if it's been set improperly?

Comment: You saved me! On my linux, I set ORACLE_HOME at /root/.bash_profile, but it should be with user oracle and in /home/oracle/.bash_profile. Below I will add detail guide.

Answer (score 0):

According to @Hankuna Matata's guide. If you run oracle on CentOS or other linux Try to set ORACLE_HOME in user oracle .bash_profile. My .bash_profile located at /home/oracle. Append following lines:

```
export ORACLE_BASE=/home/oracle/app/oracle
export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
export ORACLE_SID=orcl
```

Then run the command with user oracle in terminal

```
$ source .bash_profile
$ lsnrctl start
```

If you see lines end with "The command completed successfully" instead error message, you got it!